# AngularFire karma test never reaches promise callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, karma-jasmine, angularfire

I have a controller that uses `AngularFire`'s `$firebaseObject`.
When the controller initializes, it sets the reference to Firebase, and uses `$loaded` function to verify that data from Firebase is actually there. Here is a simplified code of the controller:

```
myModule.controller('VotingQuestionsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseObject',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseObject) {

        var baseRef = new Firebase("https://somefirebaserepo.firebaseio.com/pathtomyobjects"),
            topicsRef = baseRef.child("topics");                

        var topics = $firebaseObject(topicsRef);            
        $scope.dataLoaded = false;
        topics.$loaded().then(function() {
            $scope.dataLoaded = true;
            topics.$bindTo($scope, 'topics').then(function() {
                //do some stuff                    
            });
        }, function(error) {
            $scope.dataLoaded = true;
            console.log("oh no!");
        });
```

This controller works pretty good in real life. The problem is testing it with Karma. No matter what I tried, my test spec never reaches the callback for `topics.$loaded` (neither the success function nor the error function).

Here is the current state of my test spec:

```
describe('VotingQuestionsCtrl', function() {
  var $controller, $scope, $rootScope, $firebaseObject, $stateParams, $q, baseRef, $timeout;

  beforeEach(module('wsApp.controllers'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    MockFirebase.override();
    $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
    $q = $injector.get('$q');
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $firebaseObject = $injector.get('$firebaseObject');
    $rootScope.user = {username: "user"};
    $rootScope.selectedSim = {phase: "phase1"};        
    baseRef = new Firebase("https://somefirebaserepo.firebaseio.com/pathtomyobjects");
    baseRef.set({topics: {simId: {phase1: "bla"}}, users: {}});
    baseRef.flush();
  }));

  it('loads the controller', function(done) {
    $controller('VotingQuestionsCtrl', {$scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, $firebaseObject: $firebaseObject});
    $scope.$digest();

    setTimeout(function() {
        expect($scope.dataLoaded).toBeTruthy();
        done();
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

I've tried all sorts of flushing, digesting, whatever... the test goes through the rest of the controller, but the async part just doesn't work.